# ESlint - get all configs for a specific path

Tags: eslint

is it possible to get all ESlint config files and rules for a specific path.

I have the following file structure:

```
your-project
├── package.json
└─┬ tests
        ├── .eslintrc
        └── test.js
```

I want to get an object or array like this:

```
{
  'your-project/package.json': {
    /* all rules and settings from package.json */
  },
  'your-project/tests/.eslintrc': {
    /* all rules and settings from .eslintrc */
  }
}
```

Are there tools from ESlint or do I have to scan all the folders manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using latest version of ESLint (v2.4.0) you can use `eslint --print-config filename` command line option. It should output you all of the rules that will be used for a given file as well as all of the declared globals and environments.

Comment: That looks good! But unfortunately I need to know from which file the rules are coming. I think I have to do it manually...

Comment: You can also run with the `--debug` flag to get the list of all of the config files that are being used.